# Chrome browser can't find partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I use the following in my controller to add tasks to my project model using ajax.

```
def task_add
    project = Project.find(params[:project])
    @task = ProjectTask.new(:description => params[:description])
    project.project_tasks << @task
    render :partial => 'task'
end
```

and my ajax call:

```
$('#task-add').click(function(){
    var taskDesc = $('#task-description').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/project_task_add",
        data: ({project:<%= @project.id %>, description:taskDesc}),
        success: function(data){
            var data = $('<div/>').append(data);
            $('#tasks').append($('#new-task', data).html());
        }
    });         
});
```

It works fine in Firefox but Chrome gives the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Digging deeper in the chrome dev tools I find the following response:

```
<h1>Template is missing</h1>
<p>Missing partial projects/task with {:locale=&gt;[:en, :en], :formats=&gt;[:js,            :&quot;*/*&quot;], :handlers=&gt;[:erb, :rjs, :rhtml, :builder, :rxml]} in view paths &quot;/home/user/apps/my_app/app/views&quot;, &quot;/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.1.5/app/views&quot;</p>
```

The _task.html.erb partial exists under /views/projects/ and Firefox renders it just fine. I don't understand what's different in Chrome... any ideas?

Comment: the method of the request is :js , are you using link_to_remote helper ? i think rails is try to render _task.js.rjs not _task.html.erb ... post the form related to your action and your routes.rb for more help! bye

Comment: Please include the javascript code that you are using to make the call.

Comment: Can you post the HTTP request for the failing page from Chrome (and Firefox)?

Comment: andrea was right! render :partial => 'projects/task.html.erb' did the trick. It works fine now. andrea if you want to post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method of the request is :js.
I think rails is try to render _task.js.rjs not _task.html.erb .
You could explicit It

```
render :partial => 'projects/task.html.erb'
```

but i think that you could change the view from wich request is generated so that they dont have params method js Or render an ajax response.

post your view if you want more help!

Comment: Just updated the question to include my ajax call. Not sure if there is a way to change the method in the params from js to html.

Comment: no , I know ... maybe you could try http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ instead of $.ajax. but I dont know if the params js is skipped ... let me know if you try. have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

This is expecting your partial to be called `app/views/projects/task.js.erb` (as figured out by the `formats` part of your error, not `app/views/projects/task.html.erb`. You probably only have the `html` partial defined.